# How can I change the animation style of a modal UIViewController?

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch

I'm currently displaying a UIViewController like this:

```
[[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:modalViewController animated:YES];
```

and hiding it like this:

```
[self.navigationController dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

The animation is "slide up from the bottom"... then slide back down.  How can I change the animation style?  Can I made it fade in/out?

Cheers!

Answer (score 60, accepted):

Marcus Zarra posted a great solution to this on the SDK mailing list:

```
UIViewController *controller = [[[MyViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
UIViewAnimationTransition trans = UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp;
[UIView beginAnimations: nil context: nil];
[UIView setAnimationTransition: trans forView: [self window] cache: YES];
[navController presentModalViewController: controller animated: NO];
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

There are transitions for flipping and page-curling. If you are set on fading, can try adjusting your new view's alpha:

```
UIViewController *controller = [[[MyViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
controller.view.alpha = 0.0;
[navController presentModalViewController: controller animated: NO];
[UIView beginAnimations: nil context: nil];
controller.view.alpha = 1.0;
[UIView commitAnimations];
```

However, what you probably want is a crossfade, or at least a fade-over. When the UINavigationController switches to a new view, it removes the old one. For this effect, you're probably better off just adding a new view to your existing UIViewController and fading its alpha in over time.

Note: If you are not in your app delegate [self window] will not work. Use self.view.window , thanks to user412500's post for pointing this out.

Comment: This is old! See Simo Salminen's answer below! MrDatabase you should switch this

Answer (score 194):

For iPhone 3.0+, a basic crossfade is easiest to do like this:

```
modalViewController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
[[self navigationController] presentModalViewController:modalViewController
                                               animated:YES];
```

Comment: Works perfectly!!! It took me a couple of seconds to realize that the transition has to be applied to the viewController that is being presented and not self.

Comment: You can do this in Interface Builder, by adding a modal segue and setting the transition to `Cross Dissolve`, for example.

Answer (score 8):

To update for alpha fading in iOS 4:

```
modalController.view.alpha = 0.0;
[self.view.window.rootViewController presentModalViewController:modalController animated:NO];
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                 animations:^{modalController.view.alpha = 1.0;}];
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be `[self.view.window]` in order for the code to work

(at least that's the way that it is in ios 3.2)