# How to customize the animation time of "presentModalViewController"?

Tags: animation, uiviewcontroller, presentmodalviewcontroller

any ideas how to customize the animation time of a viewcontroller when using  "presentModelViewController"?

Thanks for any hints on that one..

Answer (score 0):

Someone had the same question a few years ago
Maybe the solutions still work for iOS 4.2...
[Can I increase the animation speed of presentModalViewController?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1055754/can-i-increase-the-animation-speed-of-presentmodalviewcontroller)