# iPhone: Animate dismissModalVieController

Tags: iphone, animation

Im using `[[self modalViewController] dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];` to remove a view. How do I apply a cross-dissolve animation to this? By using this code only, it shows a default 'slide down' animation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try this

```
[self modalViewController].modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve;
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an answer to this question [here:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237310/how-can-i-change-the-animation-style-of-a-modal-uiviewcontroller/2006694#2006694)

Comment: Thats works for presentModalViewController, but how do I use that for dismissing the view?

Comment: set the transition style, then call -dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES

Answer (score 0):

```
self.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCrossDissolve
```