# Scrolling PopUpController (like in ITunes for Ipad)

Tags: ios, ipad

I'm trying to find any coding example of a scrolling PopUpController, like the one you would see on ITunes when using an IPad device.  Ex. you you choice a movie from the menu, you are presented with a new scroll view that scrolls through different information about the movie.  It's a nice look and I'm considering working it into a project I'm working on.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a standard modal view controller.  Here is a an example on changing the animation from the standard slide up from bottom:

[Change modal view controller animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/237310/how-can-i-change-the-animation-style-of-a-modal-uiviewcontroller)

Comment: I can already control animation.  It's the actual scrolling of the pages w/in what looks to be a popupover.  It may not be a popovercontroller.  When the popupover appears the main screen darkens.  The active window is now has a scrolling ability to display information on the content chosen.

Comment: A UIPopoverController is generally not centered on the screen while a modal UIViewController is centered.  Is the element you're requested centered?

Comment: I think you just need a UIViewController whose view is a UIScrollView instead of a UIView.  Then you can scroll the content like in iTunes.

Comment: Actually the more I look into this, it's probably not a popupcontroller (although my current popupcontroller is pops to specific x,y coords).  Possible What I need is a defined ScrollView that merely shows paged information in the scrollview.  The use of the storyboard is what makes this nasty.

Comment: I believe you're correct in your last assessment.. this is essentially where I'm at now.  I think my problem comes into loading these new view in a storyboard.  Am I then forced to programmatically create all the information in each view?

Comment: Unfortunately, I have not used the storyboards.  This might help you switch out the standard UIView for a UIScrollView in a UIViewController: http://redartisan.com/2010/5/23/scrolling-with-uiscrollview